# java.net.BindException:JVM Bind

Tags: java, sockets, jvm

I keep running into this error:
"Exception on new ServerSocket: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind".
I have tried using netstat to make sure that nothing is running on port(1500). Any advice?

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Server 
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

Server(int Port)
{   
/* create socket server and wait for connection requests */
try 
{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1500, 0, InetAddress.getByName("69.61.210.196"));
        System.out.println("Server waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        while(true) 
        {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  // accept connection
    System.out.println("New client asked for a connection");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       new Server(1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an OS issue. Are you sure that the user that is running the JVM has enough OS permissions to bind to port 1500?

Comment: Are you sure 69.61.210.196 is an IP address of the local machine? And why not just bind to 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the IP address you are trying to bind to is your external IP address of the network and not your machine IP.

Recommend trying to bind to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` instead.

To get your machine IP use from command line on windows `ipconfig` and on linux `ifconfig`.